# Getting blank window on my jar application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, processing, minim

I am working on a Java project which uses processing and minim libraries. I am using Intellij as IDE. I have successfully created my program and it runs well on IDE. Now I have exported it as .jar file using build artifacts option. Now the problem is that when I open my jar file it only shows blank window, nothing more.

I have included both libraries and also selected option to extract them into target jar file. So, please suggest a solution.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please show a minimal working example that creates this behavior. See [mcve] for some tips on how to create a code example.

Comment: I suggest that you run your program from the command-line with `java -jar <your jar file name>`. This will allow you to see any error messages.

Comment: What @Code-Apprentice just said is essential. You need to run this via the command line so you can see any errors you're getting.

Comment: Thank you guys for your support. I figured out a way. The path of images I used was relative. Somehow when generating jar, it was getting changed. So, I put the images in src folder and changed the path. Rebuild the jar and problem is solved.